# Django & Bootstrap sample project

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Dears, I'm new in web development, I almost know Django and Bootstrap, I wonder if there was a sample project written with these two framework in Github or anywhere it could be more helpful to review and learning. I couldn't find sample, can anyone introduce me one?

Comment: you can create a simple django project and load bootstrap and js files  based on django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, didn't found such thing, but in exchange, you can install this django package: https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3

Is for integrating Bootstrap 3 with Django in a few steps, pretty easy as the matter in fact